# JQ does not contain for "key": "value" JSON structure

Tags: jq

The question is similar to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53512985/jq-filter-array-does-not-contain), but the JSON structure is different.

In my usecase JSON has an arrays with key:value data:

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "name":"banana",
         "tags":[
            {
               "id":"yellow"
            },
            {
               "id":"long"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"apple",
         "tags":[
            {
               "id":"red"
            },
            {
               "id":"round"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"orange",
         "tags":[
            {
               "id":"orange"
            },
            {
               "id":"round"
            },
            {
               "id":"colored"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

What required is to filter the only elements that do not have certain keyword - "red" for instance.

When i use `jq '.data[] | select(.tags[].id | index( "red" ))'` it brings me the correct resut of 'apple' (as it has `"id": "red"`) and 'orange' (as it has `"id": "colored"`).

However, when i add the negation `jq '.data[] | select(.tags[].id | index( "red" ) | not)'` the results are more than strange, with elements' duplication, totally enigmatic.

How can i use jq to filter the result the way it returns only elements that do not have **the exact** match among the array values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`index` works on an array, your current filter does not pass `index` to an array, therefore you're getting other results then expected.

---

```
.data[] | select([ .tags[].id ] | index("red") | not)
```

Here we create an array with all the id's `[ .tags[].id ]` and use that array to check for `red`: `| index("red") | not`

---

The above filter gives the following output:

```json
{
  "name": "banana",
  "tags": [
    {
      "id": "yellow"
    },
    {
      "id": "long"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "name": "orange",
  "tags": [
    {
      "id": "orange"
    },
    {
      "id": "round"
    },
    {
      "id": "colored"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/IBFyTOvvVyE)

---

If you want to exclude 'colored', use `contains()`:

```
.data[] | select([ .tags[].id ] | contains(["red"]) | not)
```

```json
{
  "name": "banana",
  "tags": [
    {
      "id": "yellow"
    },
    {
      "id": "long"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/tb1Y14lZbSy)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `all` to give a condition all items must meet. Here, all values in `.tags[].id` must be unequal `!=` to `"red"`:

```bash
jq '.data[] | select(all(.tags[].id; . != "red"))'
```

```json
{
  "name": "banana",
  "tags": [
    {
      "id": "yellow"
    },
    {
      "id": "long"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "name": "orange",
  "tags": [
    {
      "id": "orange"
    },
    {
      "id": "round"
    },
    {
      "id": "colored"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/VWEZfa8AsNH)

Add `.name` and use the `-r` option to only get the names:

```bash
jq -r '.data[] | select(all(.tags[].id; . != "red")).name'
```

```json
banana
orange
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/1viKd9pfrGO)